# Have a nullable relation between 2 entities, still Symfony send me a message if the form is not complete

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**QUESTION/PROBLEM**

I have a form which allow me to add an IMAGE to a SENTENCE (to do a DIAPORAMA). It is not necessary that every SENTENCE get an IMAGE so the relation is nullable=true (see below SENTENCE class in my code).

But every time I tried to modified a diaporama I got the following **message from Symfony** if one of the sentence has no image associated. (it should not try to insert an Image because the relation can be nullable, and in this cas I simply do not want to insert an image)

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Image (url, alt) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:    
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'url' cannot be null
```

( **IMPORTANT ==>** if an image is associated it works fine! )

**MY CODE:**

I got the following mapping between my entities:
DIAPO (1)<---->(n)  SENTENCE   (1) ------>(1)  IMAGE

Controller

```
 if($form->isValid()){
     foreach($diapo->getSentences() as $Sentence)
     {
       $image = $Sentence->getImage();
       $image->upload();
     }
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $em->persist($diapo);
     $em->flush();
}
```

Class DIAPO

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Sentence", mappedBy="diapo")
**/
private $Sentences;
```

Class SENTENCE

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Diapo", inversedBy="Sentences")
 **/
private $diapo;

/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
*/
private $image;
```

Class IMAGE

```
private $url;
private $alt;
private $file;
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

public function upload()
{
  // IF NO FILE (mybe I should add something here to abort the upload?)
  if (null === $this->file) {
    return ;
  }
  $name = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
  $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $name);
  $this->url = $name;
  $this->alt = $name;
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
  return 'uploads/img';
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
  return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
```

SQL DUMP ON IMAGE

```
CREATE TABLE `Image` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `alt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

Comment: Do you have any other tables that use the `URL` column as a foreign key? That error typically corresponds to a foreign key constraint that means you can't have null in that column because then no foreign column can tie itself to the table. Do a sql dump of the structure of your tables to see if there is an index on the table for that column. That would also give you the name of the index so you can look at the structure of the index and figure out what other table it is foreign to.

Comment: @ Kuhn. The problem doesn't come from the URL column (in the IMAGE table) which cannot be null. But the image column in the SENTENCE table. That colum can be null, but still doctrine seems to try to add something in it even if I haven't add anything in the form.

Comment: Are you sure? The error I see is a mysql error that specifically says: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'url' cannot be null`

Comment: the problem I have is that is try to insert an Image while there are no Image to insert. So it add an Image in the image column in SENTENCE table and then it insert a Image object in image table. But it should simply not try to add an Image...

Comment: my question is simply: **why does it try to add an image while there are no image to add?**

Comment: do a sql dump of your table and post it. The insert is likely like I said, there is a foreign key doing it. Doctrine or mysql sees the foreign key and so is trying to do the insert automatically because the table you are inserting to is the foreign key to another table. For example, table `A` and table `B`. column `B.A_ID` is a FK to `A.ID`. You can't insert a row into table `B` without there being a corresponding `A.ID`.

Comment: ok I just done it. I added it to the original question